# Is using Docker Swarm mandatory for multiple containers?

Tags: docker

First time using Docker so please bear with me.

Say in a scenario where, I have a repository for my frontend React app, and I have another separate repository for my backend express server. And I containerize them as separate docker containers - so my frontend is a container on its own and backend is a container on its own.

Now that I need to deploy them, do I deploy them individually to their own virtual servers - like 2 AWS ECS? Or should I use Docker Swarm to deploy them together to one virtual server? Not sure what to do since they are two separate repositories.

I'm open to any feedback since I've never touched docker before!

Comment: Swarm is Docker's clustered container system.  There are several other alternatives (AWS ECS, Kubernetes, ...), but for what you're describing you may not need a cluster system at all; just `docker run` the two containers on the same instance, or use a system like Compose to launch them together.

Answer (score 1):

No, as pointed out by David, swarm is for when you want to connect multiple hosts together into one big docker cluster and distribute your containers amongst them.

It also allows you to network together these containers running on different machines, like for example you can connect a backend running on your cloud VPS to a self hosted database running at your home.

If you need more scalability, Kubernetes is probably better since it's way more scalable and the more modern and adapted solution.

With a single machine, the normal docker engine is all you need to run multiple containers on that single server.